# Kubernetes how to expose a port on host node to pods?

Tags: kubernetes

We are just getting started with k8s. One of the things we need to do is expose a service running on each bare metal Ubuntu 20.04 host node to pods in k8s. The service is listening on the node's real IP as well as localhost on port 8500. Is there an easy way to do this?

I can get to port 80 and 443 on the node from inside a pod using its IP but not to 8500.

Comment: Are you sure that the service is listening on `0.0.0.0:8500`?

Comment: Yes I tested from another server: curl -v http://<host ip>:8500 works. Same thing from inside pod just sits on "Trying..."

Comment: I can get to the same service running on other nodes from inside the pod, just not to the instance running on its own node. So maybe this is some sort of security thing to not allow the pod to access random ports on its node?

Comment: Please check if your port 8500 is open. [Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/) you can find information how to do this in several ways. Additionally, did you get any error when did you try to access node on port 8500?

Comment: Yes I have checked. I can get to the service from the host with curl to its public ip. I can get to the service from other hosts with its public ip. I cannot get to it from k8s pods running on the host (node) using its public ip. I can get to it from k8s pods running on other hosts using its public ip.

Comment: Same thing happens if I deploy service in a pod using hostNetwork:true. Other pods on the same node cannot get it it, no problem from other nodes.

Comment: I have finally made some progress on this: "iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8500 -j ACCEPT" sorts it out. I didn't think that connections from inside k8s pods on the same host would get blocked by our firewall rules. Now I just need to figure out how to poke a more specific hole in the firewall.

Comment: "iptables -A INPUT -i cni0 -j ACCEPT" seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @David Tinker mentioned in the comments, problem is solved.

> connections from inside k8s pods on the same host would get blocked by our firewall rules.

So, the solution is hidden in iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i cni0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: This was helpful to understand k8s networking: https://itnext.io/kubernetes-journey-up-and-running-out-of-the-cloud-flannel-c01283308f0e